# How to bind a click event to a Leaflet canvas GridLayer

Tags: javascript, canvas, leaflet

I'm trying to bind a click event to a leaflet plug-in's extension of a canvas GridLayer (using Leaflet 1.0, with [Leaflet.MaskCanvas](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-maskcanvas)).

[From the Leaflet Documentation about GridLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#gridlayer-on), I would expect that I could bind a click to `coverageLayer` using either

```
// add event listener to determine when layer has been clicked
coverageLayer.on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('clicked the line');
});
// second (alias) method to add event listener
coverageLayer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('clicked the line');
});
```

but neither of the above seem to be working.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6py47w4/) where I've forked and tweaked the example code from the MaskCanvas plugin.

**Is there some other way to bind a click to a canvas layer in Leaflet?**

*Edit: `.on()` and `.addEventListener()` are aliases.*

*Previously the question dealt with Leaflet 0.7, and TileLayer.  From the [old Leaflet Documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-canvas), it appears that TileLayer did not have these events.  JSFiddle code has been updated to use Leaflet 1.0.*

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution? I am using leaflet 1.0.2

Comment: @Gisway I worked around this by catching all clicks and then checking the click location against an array containing all of the `L.LatLng` values plotted on the canvas layer.  If the click matched an `L.LatLng` value to within some tolerance, then I considered it to have clicked that element.  It's not pretty, but it works.  Please let me know if you find something better!

Answer (score 4):

In Leaflet 1.0, `GridLayer`s do not handle mouse/touch/pointer events (notice their [events documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#gridlayer-event) does **not** list pointer events, whereas some [other layer types do](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#interactive-layer)).

Furthermore, the DOM element containing the tiles (a `<div class='leaflet-tile-container>`) has a `pointer-events: none;` CSS rule. This makes the browser ignore pointer events (giving it a tiny bit of better performance).

You'll need to attach the events to the cells themselves (when on your custom `createTile()`) and override the `pointer-events` CSS rule.

Comment: Thank you--this is very helpful.  So then my thought would be implement inside the `createTile()` function: either `this.addEventListener('click', function(e) { console.log('clicked the tile'); });` or `tile.addEventListener('click', function(e) { console.log('clicked tile'); });`  where `tile` is the canvas.  But neither of these seems to do anything.  (I also changed the CSS to read `.leaflet-tile-container { cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto; }`).  The cursor is now a pointer, but the click still isn't registered.  I'm using Google Chrome.  Any additional suggestions, please?